# Scala How to convert my df data in to list of items

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following DF,

```
+-----+--------------+----------+
|level|var1          |var2      |
+-----+--------------+----------+
|1    |[id, id1]     |[name]    |
|2    |[add1]        |[city1]   |
|3    |[add2]        |[city2]   |
+-----+--------------+----------+
```

and I would like to store it as below,

```
val first = List(List("id","id1"), List("add1"), List("add2"))
val second = List(List("name"), List("city1"), List("city2"))
```

The logic is all the columns values should come as list of items,Please suggest me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the data frame look like bellow.

```
df.show()
  //  +-----+---------+-------+
  //  |level|     var1|   var2|
  //  +-----+---------+-------+
  //  |    1|[id, id1]| [name]|
  //  |    2|   [add1]|[city1]|
  //  |    3|   [add2]|[city2]|
  //  +-----+---------+-------+
```

and the data frame structure.

```
df.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- level: integer (nullable = true)
//  |-- var1: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
//  |-- var2: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

You can collect and convert like this.

```
val first: List[List[String]] =
    df.select("var1")
      .collect()
      .map(row =>
        row(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[String]].toList).toList
// List(List(id, id1), List(add1), List(add2))
  val second: List[List[String]] =
    df.select("var2")
      .collect()
      .map(row =>
        row(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[String]].toList).toList
// List(List(name), List(city1), List(city2))
```

Comment: its not good to use two collects when one collect can do the job as collects are expensive and rdd is recomputed as soon as an action calls upon it https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#resilient-distributed-datasets-rdds

Comment: we can use `rdd.cache()` to avoid computing every time. and then we can create data frame out of that rdd.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `collect_list` *inbuilt function* on each columns to collect as `Array[Array[String]]` and then do *type castings* to change them to `List[List[String]]` as below

**collect_list**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val tempdf = df.select(collect_list("var1").as("var1"), collect_list("var2").as("var2"))
```

should give you

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|var1                                                           |var2                                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(id, id1), WrappedArray(add1), WrappedArray(add2)]|[WrappedArray(name), WrappedArray(city1), WrappedArray(city2)]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**type casting and saving to variables**

```
val rdd = tempdf.collect().map(row => (row(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[Seq[String]]], row(1).asInstanceOf[Seq[Seq[String]]]))

val first = rdd(0)._1.map(x => x.toList).toList
//first: List[List[String]] = List(List(id, id1), List(add1), List(add2))
val second = rdd(0)._2.map(x => x.toList).toList
//second: List[List[String]] = List(List(name), List(city1), List(city2))
```